# How to set a ResourceDictionary to a ContentControl.Content?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, styles, silverlight-5.0, resourcedictionary

In my application, I have a `ContentControl` and this shows the `Content` property using `DataTemplates`.

Right now, I need to pass this `DictionaryResource` to the content property. So I did this (I'm not sure)

```
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel">
            <ContentControl.Resources>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/MathematicsBusiness.Infrastructure;component/Resources/ThemeResources.xaml" />
            </ContentControl.Resources>
        </ContentControl>
```

And this contain my dictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="40" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Georgia" />
    </Style>

    <!--<Style x:Key="TextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="40" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Georgia" />
    </Style>-->
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And it works, all the data templates show the textblocks with that style. But if I use the commented style, it does not work. It throws me an error:

> Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key TextBlockStyle

Why is happening that? If the style does not have a Key, it works. But if I set a key, it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you are using the `TextBlockStyle` key?

Answer (score 0):

If you specify a key without using it, it should not be a problem. My guess is that you are calling TextBlockStyle somewhere else (maybe your visual state or your code).

The error you are having usually happens if you are trying to use the key, but you haven't specified it in your xaml.

Other possible cause is that you are trying to use the key outisde the ContentControl.